# Error compiling iPhone tweak

Tags: jailbreak, dylib, tweak

I am trying to compile a iPhone tweak I just created and I am getting some errors I can not seem to find a solution for and help would be appreciated.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in Tweak.xm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [obj/tweakTest.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [tweakTest.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the UIKit framework in your project and add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in your .xm file.